# Project wide 'Convert Indents'

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.2

Is there a way to do a project wide `Convert Indents` in Android Studio? I've only been able to do it on individual open files, which gets repetitive quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this with the Android Studio IDE, so I resolved it with `sed -i 's;\t;    ;g' app/src/main/java/**/*.java`

`sed` is a **s**tream **ed**itor. You can find out a lot more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

`-i` tells it to edit the input files, not output it to stdout or another file.

`s;\t;    ;g` is a **s**ubstitute command, separated by semi-colons (`;`), that basicaly says substitute tabs (`\t`) with four spaces () **g**lobally (i.e., on the whole line, not just the first occurrence).

`app/src/main/java/**/*.java` is the files to edit, meaning every file in every subdirectory of `app/src/main/java/` that ends with `.java`.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not too familiar with Android project structures, so there can be files outside of the ones added in my path that should be converted.